# App function seems to re-execute and wipes out state (with React Bootstrap DropDown)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have a very simple app for learning and playing with React.
It uses one Bootstrap Dropdown and two Bootstrap buttons.

The goal is to set a state variable from the item picked in the Dropdown component, and concatenate it into the text displayed for each of the two buttons.  And that actually works for a split second, but then the page seems to reload, and it goes back to the default value ('BTC-USDT' in my sample). So I still don't understand the page load and events in React. Why is the page reloading? (I have a console.log("Start function App") which makes me believe that it is.)

Code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React,{useState} from 'react'; 
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  console.log("Start function App")
  const [getCoinPair,setCoinPair]=useState('BTC-USDT');

  const handleSelectCoinFromDropdown=(e)=>{
      console.log('Coin selected:');
      console.log(e);
      setCoinPair(e)
      // alert('Coin Selected ' + e);
  }  

  function buy() {
    alert('Clicked Buy');
  }
  function sell() {
    alert('Clicked Sell');
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
       <Dropdown onSelect={handleSelectCoinFromDropdown}>
          <Dropdown.Toggle 
              variant="secondary btn-sm" 
              id="dropdown-basic">
              Coin/Pair
          </Dropdown.Toggle>

          <Dropdown.Menu style={{backgroundColor:'#73a47'}}>
              <Dropdown.Item href="BTC-USDT">BTC-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="CRV-USDT">CRV-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="LINK-USDT">LINK-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="SUSHI-USDT">SUSHI-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="YFI-USDT">YFI-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="ZEN-USDT">ZEN-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown> 
      <br ></br>
      <br ></br>
      <Button variant='success' onClick={buy}>
          Buy {getCoinPair}
      </Button>
      <Button variant='danger' onClick={sell}>
          Sell {getCoinPair}
      </Button>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The component gets re-rendered, i.e. the function gets called again, when you change its state. That's how it's *supposed* to work, that's how the display gets updated to reflect that new state. What did you expect?

Comment: Yes, it re-renders and shows the value I picked for a split-second, then the function App runs again, and it sets the value back to the default state (BTC-USDT).  I thought the default was only supposed to happen the first time.

Comment: What makes you think the value is set back to the default state? When `useState` is called again *after* `setCoinPair(e)`, the value assigned to `getCoinPair` would be `e`. Please give a [mre].

Comment: Example, I pick SUSHI-USDT from the drop down, I see it in the button "Buy SUSHI-USDT" for about 0.5 seconds, then the page seems to reload, and the first button says "Buy BTC-USDT".  I want the button to stay with the value I set, not go back to the default.

Comment: How much more minimal can I get?

Comment: try adding `e.preventDefault()` in `handleSelectCoinFromDropdown` function

Comment: @lala - tried that at top and bottom of the function, and same result.

Comment: Another example, in Console window in browser, the page seems to be reloading.  console.log('Coin selected:') is no longer visible there.

Comment: Normally it would work. [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-81tgor) is an example doing this without `bootstrap`

Comment: Found and posted answer, it was the href= instead of eventKey=

Answer (score 1):

It is resetting because you are not pulling the correct data from the event.

Try this:

```
 const handleSelectCoinFromDropdown=(e)=>{
  setCoinPair(e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but ah-ha moment - I think it's the use of href= now.  Let me see how to put in values that are not hrefs.

Comment: If you console.log(e), in handleSelectorCoinFromDropdown, what do you get?

Comment: When I had href, it had a good value.  But now I'm trying this: <Dropdown.Item value="LINK-USDT">LINK-USDT</Dropdown.Item>, and it is null.  I need to get the value without using href I believe.

Comment: Was following this page: <Dropdown.Item value="LINK-USDT">LINK-USDT</Dropdown.Item>  I will try eventKey="SUSHI-USDT" next.

Comment: I got it working, see my answer.  Your approach gives this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined on the statement: " console.log(e.target.value);"

Comment: Ahhh. Cool. At least it got you thinking. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with using href= on the Dropdown.Item's.
I was following first few models on this page: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

They first examples on that page, not sure why, all use href=.  But later on that page, they give an example with "eventKey=" instead of "href=".
I believe the href was going to a page, such as http://localhost:3000/SUSHI-USDT, which was causing the page to reload (not my intention).

```
  <Dropdown.Menu style={{backgroundColor:'#73a47'}}>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="BTC-USDT">BTC-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="CRV-USDT">CRV-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="LINK-USDT">LINK-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="SUSHI-USDT">SUSHI-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="YFI-USDT">YFI-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="ZEN-USDT">ZEN-USDT</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
```